# What exactly is the difference between project and library types in composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a hard time figuring this out; I am also puzzled of the connection - if any - with the `create-project` command.

As far as I can tell, the only difference between `install` and `create-project` is the execution of `post-root-package-install` and `post-create-project-cmd` hooks...

Can someone shed some more light on this?

My goal is to set up a composer infrastructure where I run `create-project` and this sets up a project skeleton (creates and sets directory permissions, creates default configuration files, creates blank data stores)

Answer (score 4):

> What exactly is the difference between project and library types in composer?

Practically, there is none. It doesn't affect how composer gets executed. You can use both `install` and `create-project` with both types of package types.

This metadata is meant to inform plugins, IDE, or even packagist.org when parsing `composer.json`, but on a vainilla installation, there is no practical difference in using one or the other.

([Docs on package types](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#type))

> As far as I can tell, the only difference between `install` and `create-project` is the execution of `post-root-package-install` and `post-create-project-cmd` hooks.

The [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project) are your friends:

> You can use Composer to create new projects from an existing package. This is the equivalent of doing a git clone/svn checkout followed by a `composer install` of the vendors.

Any time you do `create-project`, `install` is executed as well. Which means that the `install` hooks are executed as well.

First it clones the whole package via the appropriate CVS (git, usually), and then immediately executes `composer install`. By default, it removes CVS information (e.g. the `.git` directory), unless one uses the `--keep-vcs` option.

`create-project` is useful to bootstrap applications, so the app's directory is setup beyond what downloading composer`s dependencies would do. You can create a skeleton directory structure, etc.

Usually one would have a package proper (that could be `require`d into an application), and a "application-skeleton" package, that would include the directory structure and would depend on the original package.

Comment: After some more digging into this, I found out probably the right question would have been "What is the difference between `require` and `create-project`", and the answer is straight-forward with some nuances: `require` adds `package` as a requirement to the already-initialized root package, while `create-project` makes a "copy" of `package` as the root package in an uninitialized dir. The nuance is that if we are talking local packages, `create-project` actually makes a symlink to the referenced package, which can be both unintuitive and dangerous. Am I right so far?

Comment: `create-project` clones the packages, and then executes `install` using the package's `composer.json` and `comopser.lock` files.`require` adds a package to `composer.json`, then to `composer.lock`, then executes `install`. Those two commands are not particularly related.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting a more succint answer to my questions, based on experimentation:

1. What is the difference between `project` and `library` types?

Absolutely none as far as `composer` is concerned. Some plugins might implement logic to treat the two package types differently though.

2. How does that relate to `require`, `install`, `create-project` commands?

In no way whatsoever. The `project` in package type has nothing to do with `project` in `create-project`.

3. How does `create-project` work?

Let's say we are talking about a single `<package>`. We have 2 workflows:

- `composer init <project_path> && composer require <package>`
- `composer create-project <package> <project_path>`

The first workflow will create a blank root package and add `<package>` as a requirement to it.

The second workflow will "clone" `<package>` into `<project_path>` as the root package.

**NB**: If you are working with local `path` type repos for development, `create-project` will actually create `<project_path>` as a symlink to `<package>`'s source dir. This is the default behavior of `path` repos, and probably a miss for `composer` in the need to treat `create-project` differently. This can create a heap of confusion (as you might be inadvertently changing and adding to `<package>`s sources while thinking you are just editing `project_path`). So for local development and testing, you are better off with `cp -A` rather than `composer create-project`.